# Spanish and english bibliography references in the same document using \bibliographystyle{dcu}

Tags: bibliographies, spanish

I've written a latex document with bibliography references in spanish and english. I wanted to know if there is way to cite in both languages. I mean, I wanted cites like:

"Author1 and Author2 (year1)" and

"Author3 y Author4 (year2)"

in the same document.

The code below show what I've done, it just produces references in english.

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
...
\begin{document}
...
...
...

%-----------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%-----------------------------------

\label{Bibliography}
\lhead{\textsc{Bibliograf\'ia}} % Change the page header to say "Bibliografía"
\bibliographystyle{dcu} % Use the "dcu" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography
\nocite*{}
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib} % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I'm not sure if `bibtex`with `natbib` let you achieve what you request easily, but `biblatex`can do it. Since you use `babel`you can do it easily: Now, my doubt is if you want to cite the same reference twice: once in Spanish and the other in English or simply cite references in Spanish or English.

Comment: Hi Aradnix, I wanted to cite once per language. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Well, my suggestion is move to [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). You can use aliases for the bibtex and natbib options and use the babel language options for cite correctly in both languages.

Answer (score 1):

The template is obsolete. An updated version can be found on latextemplates.com. It uses the new features of package `biblatex`, where it is very easy to do what you want.

[image: uzgBiblatexDifferentLanguages]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,spanish,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Wombats are cool \autocite{sigfridsson}

\selectlanguage{french}
Paulo est un canard \autocite{bertram}

\selectlanguage{spanish}
Soy un peng\"uino. \autocite{companion}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
Ich spreche alle Sprachen \autocite{brandt}
\end{document}
```