# german bibliography: "und" instead of "and"

Tags: bibliographies, languages

I just have a little question about BibDesk.

I do have a list of books which should appear in the bibliography. Some of them have more than one authors. If there are e.g. three authors it is written like this: M. Mashler, E. Solan and S. Zamir. Because I am German-speaking I want to change the "and" in a "und". Is there a possibility to fix this? I hope someone may help me.

Thank you for your help.

Ok sorry, I see it would be easier if you have an example :-).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt, open = any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm, footskip=10mm} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lit}

\end{document}
```

In BibDesk I defined the book as you can see on the picture below:

[image]

Then Latex give me this:

[image]

My goal is it to write the source as I mentioned it in red.

I hope you see what I mean. Otherwise I can explain it a bit better ;-)

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: You have to use "and" in the bibtex file. If you want "und" in your document you have to use a localized bibliography style.

Comment: if you use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` the entries usually translate to German automatically.

Comment: @naphaneal unfortunately it does not work : /

Comment: see if there is a change, when you use `babelbib`-package and add the `language`-field in the bib entries. line added in bib-entry:`language={ngerman}`

Comment: Why do you not show us a short, compilable code resulting in your problem.  Then we need not to guess, and with your rep you should know, what an MWE is ...  Just help us to help you!

Comment: Sorry :-). I have put an example^^

Comment: [Spanish and english bibliography references in the same document using \bibliographystyle{dcu}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319641)

Comment: A bit of reading in german: http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html

Answer (score 6):

Use [`babelbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babelbib) and bibliography style `babplain-lf` or `babplain-lf`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt, open = any,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm, footskip=10mm} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{babelbib}

\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}
@article { Test,
  title={Game Theory},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press},
  year={2013},
  author={Maschier, Michael and Solan, Eilon and Zamier, Shmuel},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{babplain-lf}% or babplain-fl
\bibliography{lit}

\end{document}
```

[image: bibplain-lf]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt, open = any,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm, footskip=10mm} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{babelbib}

\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}
@article { Test,
  title={Game Theory},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press},
  year={2013},
  author={Maschier, Michael and Solan, Eilon and Zamier, Shmuel},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{babplain-fl}% or babplain-lf
\bibliography{lit}

\end{document}
```

[image: babplain-lf]

The language of `and` will depend on either `language` entry in the `bib` file or current language selected with `babel`.

Much better would be to switch to [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt, open = any,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm, footskip=10mm} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}   
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}
@article { Test,
  title={Game Theory},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press},
  year={2013},
  author={Maschier, Michael and Solan, Eilon and Zamier, Shmuel},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: biblatex]

Answer (score 4):

Use the style `deplain.bst` from http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/Bibliography/german/

Comment: This link does not work anymore (11th of January 2016), please replace.

Comment: see edited answer